Compare every pair of rows per group (excluding duplicates)
I have data with 3 columns:

Name
Date
Value




name
date
value




john
2023-10-10
10


john
2023-10-15
30


john
2023-11-02
5


john
2023-11-09
2


john
2023-12-01
7


john
2023-12-14
8


lea
2024-02-04
55


lea
2024-02-10
73


lea
2024-04-15
3


lea
2024-04-18
83


lea
2024-04-28
14


lea
2024-05-16
17


lea
2024-05-20
43


lea
2024-05-25
7



I want to do a by-group comparison between each pair of rows, to get the difference of value. The expected output for just John would be:



name
date_orig
date_comparison
value_diff
date_diff
records_in_range_no_extremes




john
2023-10-10
2023-10-15
-20
-5
0


john
2023-10-10
2023-11-02
5
-23
1


john
2023-10-10
2023-11-09
8
-30
2


john
2023-10-10
2023-12-01
3
-52
3


john
2023-10-10
2023-12-14
2
-65
4


john
2023-10-15
2023-11-02
25
-18
0


john
2023-10-15
2023-11-09
28
-25
1


john
2023-10-15
2023-12-01
23
-47
2


john
2023-10-15
2023-12-14
22
-60
3


john
2023-11-02
2023-11-09
3
-7
0


john
2023-11-02
2023-12-01
-2
-29
1


john
2023-11-02
2023-12-14
-3
-42
2


john
2023-11-09
2023-12-01
-5
-22
0


john
2023-11-09
2023-12-14
-6
-35
1


john
2023-12-01
2023-12-14
-1
-13
0



Reproducible data
library(tibble)

df <-
  tibble::tribble(
   ~name,        ~date, ~value,
  "john", "2023-10-10",    10L,
  "john", "2023-10-15",    30L,
  "john", "2023-11-02",     5L,
  "john", "2023-11-09",     2L,
  "john", "2023-12-01",     7L,
  "john", "2023-12-14",     8L,
   "lea", "2024-02-04",    55L,
   "lea", "2024-02-10",    73L,
   "lea", "2024-04-15",     3L,
   "lea", "2024-04-18",    83L,
   "lea", "2024-04-28",    14L,
   "lea", "2024-05-16",    17L,
   "lea", "2024-05-20",    43L,
   "lea", "2024-05-25",     7L
  )

Based on this answer, I could try to use dplyr::left_join() to join df to itself by name. Then, we need to filter out both duplicates and same-range rows. This became cumbersome, as I had to use purrr::map() and multiple steps that make my solution slow.
I feel like there has to be a simpler way, especially given the many verbs dplyr offers.

EDIT
To address some of the comments, here is an illustration of what I mean by "pair of rows". I didn't mark all possible pairs of rows in the picture to not overwhelm with colors and lines, so imagine every pair of rows is connected by a line in a unique color.


So this is a same question, but we want a better solution?

Among others, you could maybe use dplyr::lag(), previous value, but I don't think it's faster.

What do you mean by each pair of rows?

@zx8754 this isn't exactly the same question because I don't want all possible combinations (i.e., I don't want both range A->B and range B->A because I consider them as the same).

Quick and dirty data.table solution:
setDT(df)
df[, date := as.Date(date)]
setkey(df, name, date)

res <- 
  df[df, 
     on = .(name, date < date), 
     .(
       name, value = x.value, date_org = x.date, date_com = i.date,
       value_diff = x.value - i.value, date_diff = as.integer(x.date - i.date)
      ),
      nomatch = NULL]
res[, rirno := df[.SD, on = .(name, date > date_org, date < date_com), .N, by = .EACHI]$N]
setorder(res, date_org, date_com)

res[name == "john"]

# Key: <name>
#       name   name   date_org   date_com value_diff date_diff rirno
#     <char> <char>     <Date>     <Date>      <int>     <int> <int>
#  1:   john   john 2023-10-10 2023-10-15        -20        -5     0
#  2:   john   john 2023-10-10 2023-11-02          5       -23     1
#  3:   john   john 2023-10-10 2023-11-09          8       -30     2
#  4:   john   john 2023-10-10 2023-12-01          3       -52     3
#  5:   john   john 2023-10-10 2023-12-14          2       -65     4
#  6:   john   john 2023-10-15 2023-11-02         25       -18     0
#  7:   john   john 2023-10-15 2023-11-09         28       -25     1
#  8:   john   john 2023-10-15 2023-12-01         23       -47     2
#  9:   john   john 2023-10-15 2023-12-14         22       -60     3
# 10:   john   john 2023-11-02 2023-11-09          3        -7     0
# 11:   john   john 2023-11-02 2023-12-01         -2       -29     1
# 12:   john   john 2023-11-02 2023-12-14         -3       -42     2
# 13:   john   john 2023-11-09 2023-12-01         -5       -22     0
# 14:   john   john 2023-11-09 2023-12-14         -6       -35     1
# 15:   john   john 2023-12-01 2023-12-14         -1       -13     0


A dplyr approach:
library(dplyr)
df |>
  left_join(df, join_by(name, date < date)) |>
  mutate(value_diff = value.x - value.y,
         date_diff = as.Date(date.x) - as.Date(date.y)) |>
  mutate(rirno = row_number() - 1, .by = c(name, date.x))

result:
# A tibble: 45 × 8
   name  date.x     value.x date.y     value.y value_diff date_diff rirno
   <chr> <chr>        <int> <chr>        <int>      <int> <drtn>    <dbl>
 1 john  2023-10-10      10 2023-10-15      30        -20  -5 days      0
 2 john  2023-10-10      10 2023-11-02       5          5 -23 days      1
 3 john  2023-10-10      10 2023-11-09       2          8 -30 days      2
 4 john  2023-10-10      10 2023-12-01       7          3 -52 days      3
 5 john  2023-10-10      10 2023-12-14       8          2 -65 days      4
 6 john  2023-10-15      30 2023-11-02       5         25 -18 days      0
 7 john  2023-10-15      30 2023-11-09       2         28 -25 days      1
 8 john  2023-10-15      30 2023-12-01       7         23 -47 days      2
 9 john  2023-10-15      30 2023-12-14       8         22 -60 days      3
10 john  2023-11-02       5 2023-11-09       2          3  -7 days      0
# ℹ 35 more rows


Try this:
#create a new column for the dates
require(dplyr)
require(data.table)
df<-df |> group_by(name) |> mutate(Rank = rank(date))
#create a function that works on a group
f<-function(sn) {
    dates<-setNames(as.data.frame(t(combn(sn$date, 2))), c("date_orig", "date_comparison"))
    value<-combn(sn$value, 2, FUN = \(x) x[1]-x[2] )
    ranks<-combn(sn$Rank, 2, FUN = \(x) x[2]-x[1] - 1)
    cbind(name = sn$name[1], dates, value_diff = value, records_in_range_no_extremes = ranks)
}
#Split ad apply
rbindlist(lapply(split(df, df$name),f))

